# Room SQLite: Using strftime to calculate how old a record since it is created

Tags: sqlite, android-room, strftime

I am trying to create a query that delete all records that are 30 days old and above. Using ChatGPT this is what it came up

```
DELETE FROM posts WHERE strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%s', date) >= 30*24*60*60
```

But upon executing this, it doesn't delete items that are already 30 days old and only deletes when it reached 31 days.

I am testing it where `date` is `2024-02-29T23:00:00` with the current date being March 31 3:00 AM. Timezone is GMT +8. I am expecting the `>=` behavior but it seems I only get `>`, is there something I am missing? Is there inclusive/exclusive happening here?

Comment: Try using just one day insted of 30 to make it easier to reason about dates. It seems to work for me.

Comment: I believe that `now` will be UTC and that you may therefore need to use the `localtime` modifier.

Comment: @MikeT will try, this is my speculation too that the generated date using `now` is UTC which then will have some offset.

Comment: @MikeT replacing `now` with `localtime` does not work. Did you mean `datetime(date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')` ?

Comment: Either `strftime('%s','now','localtime') - strftime('%s',date) >= (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)` or `datetime('now','localtime','-30 days') >= datetime(date)`

Comment: Added answer along the lines of the comments I made

Comment: It worked, I didn't realize I haven't provided what current date I am using to test the 30 days. Updated the question for future viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that `now` is UTC whilst your values are local time.

If so then you need to adjust one to match the other.

You could use the 'localtime' modifier to change `now` to be local or alternately use the 'utc' modifier to change the `date` to UTC.

Using `localtime` then you could use:-

```
.... WHERE strftime('%s','now','localtime') - strftime('%s',date) >= (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)
```

or the simpler

```
.... WHERE datetime('now','localtime','-30 days') >= datetime(date)
```

- you may wish to refer to https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#modifiers (and perhaps other sections).
- the use of `datetime(date)`, instead of just `date` (*the column name*) caters for the `T` between the date and time which would otherwise produce incorrect results.
- the `-30 days` or `-30 day` is yet another modifier

> replacing now with localtime does not work.

Will not work because there is no date/time value `now` would be required as that is the date/time value of when the statement/sql is executed. `localtime` adjusts a date/time value from UTC to localtime (`utc` does the reverse).

> Did you mean datetime(date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime').

NO, that will have undesired results (will produce NULL) as

- date is not a number (`unixepoch` is  saying that the date/time value is a unix timestamp rather than a julian day *(more complex that this simplified explanation)*), and
- it would, if the date/time value, were considered acceptable, adjust to a localtime it as if it were  a UTC time (GMT +16 hours, from GMT +8).
- so use `localtime` to adjust `now` to the localtime or use `utc` to adjust the date in localtime to UTC